# Plotting legend using multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I intend to plot a dataframe,df using scatter plot for column:**Dvicetimestamp**  against another column: **ID** . The dataframe,df looks like this:

```
Index    Dvicetimestamp      eventName     ID
0       01:11:24.210000        ABC         4  
1       01:11:30.224000        CDE         6
2       02:16:30.210000        CDE         6
3       02:27:30.211000        CDE         6
2       01:30:40.212000        DEF         8    
3       01:35:23.122000        CDE         6   
4       02:22:22.145000        CDE         6   
5       02:26:11.222000        DEF         8
        ...                    ...         ...
```

However, I intend to have a legend such that each unique colour has its **ID** and corresponding **eventName** displayed on the graph.  In showing the graph, how can i make the x-axis ticks be 1 hour interval. However, i get error: KeyError: 0

Here is the code i have tried:

```
nums = np.array([time2num(di) for di in df['Dvicetimestamp']])
def my_formatter(x, pos=None):
    d = matplotlib.dates.num2date(x)
    if len(str(d.minute)) == 1:
       mn = '0{}'.format(d.minute)
    else:
       mn = str(d.minute)
    if len(str(d.hour)) == 1:
       hr = '0{}'.format(d.hour)
    else:
       hr = str(d.hour)
    return hr+':'+mn

major_formatter=FuncFormatter(my_formatter)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_formatter)
labels = set(df['ID']);
ax.scatter(nums,df['ID'],s=20,c=df['ID'], marker = 'o', cmap = cm.tab20 )
xmin = df['Dvicetimestamp'][0]-datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
xmax = df['Dvicetimestamp'] 
[len(df['DviceTimeStamp'])-1]+datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
ax.set_xlim((xmin,xmax))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Reading the question it seems to be about timestamps and the x axis. But reading the title it seems to be about the legend of the scatter plot? Also the time2num function is missing. Please also include a usable version of your dataframe.

Comment: I intend to want a legend of the scatterplot  where the ID and eventName column are representing each colour. Also, i would love the x-axis ticks to be spaced 1 hourly when displayed